# Is it correct to add a `div` in a link?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

Is it correct to add a `div` in a link?
I have some icons on my website, which through bootstrap when I mouse over them, increase the size slightly. The icons are within two div. I want that when clicking on the icon, in addition to that they increase in size, they take me to another page my site. I show you one of the div:

```
<section class="ulockd-service-three">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-2">
      <div class="ulockd-srvc-column-two one text-center">
        <div class="ulockd-srvc-details-two">
          <div class="ulockd-srv-icon-two"><span class="flaticon work"> 
          </span>
          </div>
          <h5>Safety Work</h5>
       </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

I have tried several ways to put the link, and finally I found one that redirects me to the desired page, but I do not know if it is the most correct way to do it, I do not think it is appropriate, it does not seem aesthetic.

This is how the link works:

```
<section class="ulockd-service-three">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-2">
      <div class="ulockd-srvc-column-two one text-center">
        <div class="ulockd-srvc-details-two">
          <a href="about.html"><div class="ulockd-srv-icon-two">
            <span class="flaticon-work"> </span>
          </div></a>
          <h5>Safety Work</h5>
       </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

What I want to say is that if it is within the allowed, taking into account everything, including if Google liked it or not.
Can you tell me the correct way to add a link to the icon without breaking the magnifying effect?

Thank you

I EDIT THE QUESTION:
I add css so you can help me, I hope to add what is necessary.
I searched for what I thought might affect the `span`

I EDIT THE QUESTION:
I add css and code snippet
What I want is to know if the way I put the link is correct, correct adding a div inside a link tag    , if the syntax is correct.

I show a fragment of the code,

I do not know how to correctly add the "FLATICON" CDN, so you can not see the icon, if you can correct that for me to make it work, I would appreciate it.

```css
.ulockd-srvc-column-two:hover .ulockd-srv-icon-two span {
  transform: scale(1.2);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.2);
  -o-transform: scale(1.2);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.2);
}

.ulockd-fservice-box .db-overlayer span {
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  bottom: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 48px;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  padding: 0 10px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
}
.ulockd-fservice-box.style2 span {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  position: absolute;
}

.time_circles{position:relative;width:100%;height:100%}.time_circles > div{position:absolute;text-align:center}.time_circles > div > h4{margin:0;padding:0;text-align:center;text-transform:uppercase;font-family:'Century Gothic',Arial}.time_circles > div > span{display:block;width:100%;text-align:center;font-family:'Century Gothic',Arial;font-size:300%;margin-top:.4em;font-weight:700}

.ulockd-srv-icon {
  padding: 10px;
}
.ulockd-srvc-column .ulockd-srv-icon {
  color: #fff;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 36px;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  margin-top: 9px;
  padding: 8px 13px;
  position: relative;
}
.ulockd-srv-icon {
  padding: 10px;
}
.ulockd-srvc-column .ulockd-srv-icon {
  color: #fff;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 36px;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  margin-top: 9px;
  padding: 8px 13px;
  position: relative;
}
.ulockd-srvc-column .srv-icon {
  font-size: 60px;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}
.ulockd-srvc-column:hover  .srv-icon{
  transform: scale(1.4);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.4);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.4);
  -o-transform: scale(1.4);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.4);
}
.ulockd-ap-srv-icon {
  background-color: #393939;
  padding: 10px;
}
.ulockd-ap-srvc-column{
  margin-bottom: 45px;
  position: relative;
}
.ulockd-ap-srvc-column .ulockd-ap-srv-icon {
  color: #fff;
  float: left;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-top: 9px;
  position: relative;
}  
.ulockd-ap-srv-icon::before {
  background-color: #393939;
  border-left: 4px solid #fff;
  border-right: 10px solid #393939;
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
  left: -33%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  transform: skewX(9deg);
  -webkit-transform: skewX(9deg);
  -moz-transform: skewX(9deg);
  -o-transform: skewX(9deg);
  -ms-transform: skewX(9deg);
  width: 44%;
}
.ulockd-srv-icon-two {
  padding: 10px;
}
.ulockd-srvc-column-two {
  padding: 10px;
  position: inherit;
  margin-top: -200px;
  z-index: 999;
}
.ulockd-srvc-column-two.one {
  margin-top: 0;
}
.ulockd-srvc-column-two:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.ulockd-srvc-column-two:hover .ulockd-srv-icon-two span {
  transform: scale(1.2);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.2);
  -o-transform: scale(1.2);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.2);
}
.ulockd-srvc-column-two .ulockd-srv-icon-two {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 60px;
  line-height: 1.3em;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
}
.ulockd-srv-icon-two{
  padding-bottom: 0;
}
.ulockd-srvc-details-two {
  padding-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://sstatic.net/so/favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>

<!--THIS IS THE NATURAL WAY OF THE DIV-->

       <section class="ulockd-service-two parallax" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.3">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      
      <div class="col-xxs-12 col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
     <div class="ulockd-srvc-column three text-center ulockd-mrgn650">
      <div class="srv-icon text-thm1"><span class="flaticon-farm-2"></span></div>
      <div class="srvc-details">
       <h3>Excellent Services</h3>
       <p>Consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugiat perspiciatis necessitatibus beatae debitis repudiandae illo nihil commodi consequuntur ipsum iusto.</p>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
      </div>
    </div>
   </section>
      
       <!--AND THIS IS THE ONLY WAY I GOT TO ADD THE LINK WHEN WE CLICK THE ICON, SO THAT IT WORKS WITHOUT BREAKING THE STYLES OF THIS. And the one that I need to know if the syntax is correct-->
       
              <section class="ulockd-service-two parallax" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.3">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      
      <div class="col-xxs-12 col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
     <div class="ulockd-srvc-column three text-center ulockd-mrgn650">
          <!--this line is the one that I modify-->
      <a href="about.html"><div class="srv-icon text-thm1"><span class="flaticon-farm-2"></span></div></a>
      <div class="srvc-details">
       <h3>Excellent Services</h3>
       <p>Consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugiat perspiciatis necessitatibus beatae debitis repudiandae illo nihil commodi consequuntur ipsum iusto.</p>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
      </div>
    </div>
   </section>
   
   <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The HTML would be syntactically incorrect. Use spans instead of divs. Use css to make span behave like a div (`display: block?`)

Comment: The truth is that I do not know very well how is the CSS written, since I work from a template that uses bootstrap.
If I delete the span, the icon disappears. I do not know how to preserve the styles and add the link

Comment: If you don't add the CSS or a link to the stylesheet, we can't really predict what kind of changes in this code may look like.

Comment: I added css to the question, I hope I have added what is necessary so that you can help me @ArnoTenkink , thank you.

Comment: If I paste the provided CSS and HTML together I'm still not getting a styled element. Please make a full code snippet with style to replicate what your seeing on your own development site.

Comment: I have returned to edit the question, @ArnoTenkink

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the div operation span directly or maybe better

```
<section class="ulockd-service-three">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-2">
      <div class="ulockd-srvc-column-two one text-center">
        <div class="ulockd-srvc-details-two">
          <a href="about.html"><span class="flaticon-work"> </span></a>
          <h5>Safety Work</h5>
       </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks for the contribution, but if I do it in the way that you advise me, the icon becomes minuscule, not even distinguishable. Thank you.